# Instantiate a class of type abstract class

Tags: typescript

The function createBob has a TS error because Person is an abstract class and I can't instantiate it.
I want the function to only accept the classes that extend Person and are not abstract.

```
abstract class Person {
    protected abstract type?: string
    constructor(private name: string) {}

    protected greet() {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`)
    }
}


class Student extends Person {
    type = "Student" 
    constructor(type: string) {
        super(type)
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
    type = "teacher"
    constructor(type: string) {
        super(type)
    }
}

function createPerson(ClassThatInheritsPerson: typeof Person): Person {
    /*
    * The ClassThatInheritsPerson should only accept classes that extend Person but are not Person
    */
    return new ClassThatInheritsPerson()
}

const teacher1 = createPerson(Teacher) // should be allowed
const student1 = createPerson(Student) // should be allowed
const person = createPerson(Person) // shouldn't be allowed
```

Comment: Since you are trying to create `ClassThatInheritsPerson` without any arguments, both `Student` and `Teacher` should not be allowed. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass types and use them to instantiate classes like you can do in other languages.  What you need to do is change the type of createPerson's argument to a constructor by using `new() => Person`.  This will allow you create new instances of Person, while throwing a compiler error for the abstract case:

```
function createPerson<T extends Person>(ctor: new() => T): T {
    return new ctor();
}

const student1 = createPerson(Student); // should be allowed
const teacher1 = createPerson(Teacher); // should be allowed
const foo =  createPerson(Foo); // typeof Foo isn't asignable to () => Person
const person1 = createPerson(Person) // Error: Cannot assign an abstract
```

A few other suggestions.  Don't make type protected - that will be useful for discriminating types later.  You could also either make the type of type a string literal, or use a generic parameter to specify the type.  That way something like `student.type` won't be type *string*, but type *'student*'.

```
abstract class Person<T extends string> {
    constructor(public readonly type: T) { }
}

class Student extends Person<'Student'> {
    constructor() {
        super('Student');
    }
}

class Teacher extends Person<'teacher'> {
    constructor() {
        super('teacher');
    }
}
```